# C# Basic. Multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to programming and would be very grateful for the help.
The main problem is that do not understand how to get and operate the user's input on two arrays.

#### Current output

[image: my output]

#### Desired output

[image: How the output should look]

#### Current solution

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] name = { "Single", "Double", "Luxury", "Penthouse" };
    double[] price = { 45.50, 99.99, 165.25, 1095.50 };
    Console.WriteLine("Room Types\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < name.Length;  i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. " + name[i] + " " + "$" + price[i] + " per night");
    }
    Console.Write("\nPlease select a room type 1, 2, 3 or 4: ");
    int room = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Please enter the number of nights: ");
    int nights = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you, the total cost for staying in the ? room for 5 nights is " + nights * room);
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `price[room] * nights` ? or `price[room-1] * nights` depending

Comment: Do you have to code it like this (assignment restriction)? I ask because normally in OO when we want to keep data together like a rooms name and it's price we would make a Room class with a name and a price properties and then have an array of Room..

Comment: Yes, the task doesn't require OO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there, I have made your loop use the index E.g `{i+1}`

```
Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}. {name[i]} ${price[i]} per night")
```

The result to use the token `{nights}` and the calculation to be `{price[room-1] * nights}`

**Example**

```
string[] name = { "Single", "Double", "Luxury", "Penthouse" };
double[] price = { 45.50, 99.99, 165.25, 1095.50 };

Console.WriteLine("Room Types");

for (int i = 0; i < name.Length;  i++)
   Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}. {name[i]} ${price[i]} per night");

Console.Write("\nPlease select a room type 1, 2, 3 or 4: ");

var room = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Please enter the number of nights: ");
var nights = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine($"\nThank you, the total cost for staying in the ? room for 5 nights is {price[room-1] * nights}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output**

```
Room Types
1. Single $45.5 per night
2. Double $99.99 per night
3. Luxury $165.25 per night
4. Penthouse $1095.5 per night

Please select a room type 1, 2, 3 or 4: 2
Please enter the number of nights: 2

Thank you, the total cost for staying in the ? room for {nights} nights is 199.98
```

Also note, never use `parse` type methods for user input, use `TryParse` type methods to protect against pesky users who can't read instructions.

## A more modern approach

```
internal class Program
{
   public record Room(string Name, double Price);

   public static Room[] _rooms =
   {
      new("Single", 45.50),
      new("Double", 99.99),
      new("Luxury", 165.25),
      new("Penthouse", 1095.50 ),
   };

   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      do
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Room Types");

         for (int i = 0; i < _rooms.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {_rooms[i].Name} ${_rooms[i].Price} per night");

         Console.Write($"\nPlease select a room type between 1 and {_rooms.Length} : ");

         int room;
         while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out room) || room <= 0 || room > _rooms.Length)
            Console.Write("Omg, you had one job, follow the instructions : ");

         Console.Write("Please enter the number of nights : ");

         int nights;
         while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nights))
            Console.Write("Omg, you had one job, follow the instructions : ");

         Console.WriteLine($"\nThank you, the total cost for staying in the ? room for {nights} nights is {_rooms[room - 1].Price * nights}");
         Console.WriteLine("Game over... press any key to play again, or enter to exit");


      } while (Console.ReadLine() == null);

      Console.WriteLine("be gone...");
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
Room Types
1. Single $45.5 per night
2. Double $99.99 per night
3. Luxury $165.25 per night
4. Penthouse $1095.5 per night

Please select a room type between 1 and 4 : fgdsfgdsfg
Omg, you had one job, follow the instructions : 2
Please enter the number of nights : 2

Thank you, the total cost for staying in the ? room for 2 nights is 199.98
Game over... press any key to play again, or enter to exit

be gone...
```

Comment: Good use of `record` but still didn't fix the `in the ? room` bug.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is the console output and the composition of strings. It is better to use string interpolation to compose strings with characters and values.

For example `Console.WriteLine( $"The value is {x}" );` where the program will insert the value of `x` in the string when it is displayed.

Specifically for your code, note that arrays are `0`-indexed which means the price for room type #1 is stored in `price[0]`, and for room type #2 in `price[1]`. It is a bit confusing as the index represents an `offset` in memory from the first value (or it used to in `C` days, and the convention is retained).

As you can see in the code below the cost for the rooms is evaluated with

```
decimal cost = nights * price[room-1];
```

which uses the array index `room-1` for that reason. Also, I switched to `decimal` types which are better for currency and display with the currency symbol `$` when rendered using the code `c`. For example the line

```
Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {name[i]} {price[i]:c2} per night");
```

displays the `price[i]` value using currency `c` with `2` decimal places.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] name = { "Single", "Double", "Luxury", "Penthouse" };
        decimal[] price = { 45.50m, 99.99m, 165.25m, 1095.50m };
        Console.WriteLine("Room Types");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {name[i]} {price[i]:c2} per night");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Please select a room type 1, 2, 3 or 4: ");
        int room = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of nights: ");
        int nights = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        decimal cost = nights * price[room-1];
        Console.WriteLine($"Thank you, the total cost for staying in the {name[room-1]} room for {nights} nights is {cost:c2}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

PS. Avoid printing `\n` for new line, as the correct way, is to either use `WriteLine()` or to use the string stored in `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, you got me back to multiples of 5.. I have major OCD!

Comment: @TheGeneral - I did not downvote.

Comment: All good either way :)